# Chinese-English translation

Tags: translation

On a plaque in the Zhalan Cemetery there seems to be an inconsistency. In the English text the burial date of Matteo Ricci is 1611 while in the Chinese text it appears to be 1610. Does the Chinese text say something else and is the English *not* an exact translation? (E.g. the Chinese speaks of date of death and English speaks of burial date.)

[image]

Comment: Chinese has more details: 明万历三十八年（１６１０年）利氏在京病逝,翌年入葬此地 (Ricci died of illness in 1610 in the capital, was buried here the following year)

Comment: @user6065 the comments section is not for posting answers.

Comment: ever since https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/differentiating-between-dove-and-pigeon-in-chinese
 some users have restricted themselves to comments afraid of being marked down by powerful vengeful other users

Comment: @user6065 I think you’re overreacting..

Comment: Obviously the English version omitted many more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chinese text says "he died in 1610 and was buried here in the next year", the English text is just an indirect tranlation.

Comment: what happened to the comment on this answer? Why did it disappear?

Comment: @user6065 Oh great, I must've missed the comment. What was it?

Comment: it called attention to comment #1, but since it was deleted earlier, the powers that be presumably will delete the present one also (why do they not just hide it?)

Comment: Should be "tran**s**lation".